# System Table to get Schema Name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am querying the `[sys].[objects]` table in SSMS.

It gives me a schema_id, but not the schema name. What table should I query to get the schema name value?

Comment: It's, unsurprisingly, called `schemas`.

Comment: As it happens, `sys.schemas`. also see function `Schema_name(id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join to `sys.schemas` or use the `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` function.

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id) AS schema_name, o.name AS object_name, o.type_desc AS object_type
FROM sys.objects AS o
ORDER BY schema_name, object_name;

SELECT s.name AS schema_name, o.name AS object_name, o.type_desc AS object_type
FROM sys.objects AS o
JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
ORDER BY schema_name, object_name;
```

Or simply pass the `schema_id` to the `schema_name` scalar function

```
Select 
    schema_name(o.schema_id)  AS schema_name,
    o.name                    AS object_name, 
    o.type_desc               AS object_type
from 
    sys.objects o
ORDER BY 
    schema_name, object_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` view:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'someCatalog'
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'someSchema'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'someTable';
```

Comment: From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), "only reliable way to find the schema of an object is to query the sys.objects catalog view. INFORMATION_SCHEMA views could be incomplete since they are not updated for all new features."